# Execute SQL scripts consecutively

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm in a situation where I need to execute sql script one after the other. The next script will be executed only if the return value of the previous script is 0. Also, I need to feed my ASP.NET Page with the statuses of the script collection, whether it's completed, on-going, cancelled or error. I'm trying to accomplish this with PageAsyncTask and by Threading but those doesn't produce the output. Any recommendation is welcome.

Edit:

I populate a gridview with an sql table where I place the log entries.
Entries are treated in the gridview differently so I manage them in the RowDataBound event of the gridview. Each link button serves a method.

```
        protected void gvProgress_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                #region CONTROL ASSIGNMENT
```

`HtmlImage icon = (HtmlImage)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[1];
            Label scriptname = (Label)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[3];
            HiddenField status = (HiddenField)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[5];
            LinkButton details = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[1];
            LinkButton pop = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[3];
            LinkButton rerun = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[5];
            LinkButton cancel = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[7];
            LinkButton start = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[9];

            #endregion

            #region CONTROLS PREPARATION

            switch (status.Value)
            {
                case "1": //Pending/Not Yet Started

                    icon.Src = "icons/pending.png";
                    details.Visible = false;
                    pop.Visible = false;
                    rerun.Visible = false;
                    cancel.Visible = false;
                    start.Visible = false;

                    break;

                case "2": //In-Progress

                    icon.Src = "icons/on-going.gif";
                    details.Visible = false;
                    pop.Visible = false;
                    cancel.Visible = true;
                    rerun.Visible = false;
                    start.Visible = false;

                    break;

                //did something similar for other statuses
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: please show some source... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: then my method loops on the gridviewrows getting the script name. If the script is not yet started, I will start it, update timestamps and status then reach the end of method. Redirects to the same page, calling the method again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered executing them all as a transaction?